# returning error code in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, error-code

I was trying to understand how Linux system calls return error codes. I bumped into [times()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html) system call. This simple system call copies some data to user space and if that operation was not successful returns `-EFAULT`:

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(times, struct tms __user *, tbuf)
{
    if (tbuf) {
        struct tms tmp;

        do_sys_times(&tmp);
        if (copy_to_user(tbuf, &tmp, sizeof(struct tms)))
            return -EFAULT;
    }
    force_successful_syscall_return();
    return (long) jiffies_64_to_clock_t(get_jiffies_64());
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why `-EFAULT`? Shouldn't it be `EFAULT` without minus?
2. Is it a common to return negative error codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [man 2 syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html):

> Note: system calls indicate a failure by returning a negative error number to the caller; when this happens, the wrapper function negates the returned error number (to make it positive), copies it to `errno`, and returns `-1` to the caller of the wrapper.

See also next answers:

- [What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752895/3866447)
- [Why doesn't a custom system call work properly with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588476/3866447)